# How to write a log to a byte or memory stream in Python?

Tags: python, memory, logging, io, byte

I want to write a running log to some kind of memory or byte stream. For example, in C# or Java, there exists a memorystream object to accomplish this. Is there some way I can facilitate writing a log to memory in Python?

Instead of this:

```
file_handle = open("log.txt", "w")
# ...
if (some_error):
    file_handle.write("event 1:...")
    file_handle.write("event 2:...")
    # ...
file_handle.close()
```

I want to write a running log to some structure in memory. What is best practice for this in Python? A String object? Something else?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe something [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [the StreamHandler class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html) best describes what you are looking for.

"The StreamHandler class, located in the core logging package, sends logging output to streams such as sys.stdout, sys.stderr or any file-like object (or, more precisely, any object which supports write() and flush() methods)."

And [this HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html) describes logging in python in detail.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for some kind of string with file-like interface, then what you need is StringIO